# asp.net pass sender to server with jquery

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to call a C# function in my aspx.cs file with jQuery. The function looks like:

```
protected void Fill(object sender, EventArgs e) { ...do s.th. with sender... }
```

in the function im getting my control I want to work with by doing a cast on the sender. How to pass the sender to server with jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this : [Implementing Client Callbacks Programmatically Without Postbacks in ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208.aspx)

**OR**

Hi you can check this article : http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2012/01/calling-server-side-function-from.html which dicuss about calling server method with the jQuery function.

cs file i.e serverside code

```
   [WebMethod]      
    public static string IsExists(string value)      
    {           return "True";      }
```

Client script

function IsExists(pagePath, dataString, textboxid, errorlableid) {
         //alert(pagePath);

```
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: pagePath,
         data: dataString,
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             $(errorlableid).show();
             $(errorlableid).html("Error");

         },
         success:
                            function(result) {
                                var flg = true;
                                if (result != null) {
                                    debugger;
                                    flg = result.d;

                                    if (flg == "True") {
                                        $(errorlableid).show();
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        $(errorlableid).hide();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
     });

 }

 function focuslost() {
     var pagePath = window.location.pathname + "/IsExists";
     var dataString = "{ 'value':'" + $("#<%= txtData.ClientID%>").val() + "' }";

     var textboxid = "#<%= txtData.ClientID%>";
     var errorlableid = "#<%= lblError.ClientID%>";
     IsExists(pagePath, dataString, textboxid, errorlableid);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't call functions just like that with jQuery. jQuery is a client scripting technology based on javascript that runs on the client browser. It doesn't know what ASP.NET is. It even less knows what a server side, ASP.NET code behind method is.

This being said, you could send an AJAX request to a server side script which in your case could be either a generic handler (.ASHX) or an .ASPX page. In this second case you could use [Page Methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/).